# Confusion about how to read the energy band diagram

Tags: energy, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, material-science, electronic-band-theory

I am not sure if I understand the energy band diagram correctly. In a pn junction situation below, before the p type material come into contact with the n type material as in figure a), an electron at the conduction band minimum in the p material has the same(or roughly the same) energy level as an electron at the conduction band minimum in the n material. Is it still true after they are fused together? If so, how come it is showing on the band diagram there is an energy difference as in figure b)?

[image]

Comment: Avoid titles starting with "Confusion regarding", "Confusion about", etc. It reduces the search-ability of the question.

Answer (score 1):

When you make a PN junction, some electrons will spill over from the N type to the P type, and some holes will spill over from the P type to the N type. This sets up a potential difference that is shifting all the energy levels of both sides, until the Fermi level is equalised between the two sides.

So, yes, an electron at the conduction band edge will be more energetic on the P side than on the N side, which explains why there would be fewer electrons in the conduction band of the P type than in the N type.